# How do i best redirect links ending in ASP to a new php site

Tags: php, apache, url, redirect, http-status-code-301

example http://www.mysite.com/contact.aspx?page=contact

to  http://www.mysite.com/contact.php

Should I use a 301 or htaccess?  I've looked at examples of both but I am still confused.

THANKS!

Comment: Belongs on [webmasters.stackexchange.com](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

A 301 would be best, permanent redirect. How you implement the 301 depends on your server. If you are using Apache, you can use mod_redirect:

```
rewriteEngine on
rewriteRule ^contact\.aspx$ http://www.mysite.com/contact.php [R=permanent,L]
```

You can also configure redirects in Apache httpd.conf (that's the way I usually do it).